# how to replace all non alphanumeric characters with space in php?

Tags: php, regex, nlp

```
$html=strip_tags($html);
$html=ereg_replace("[^A-Za-zäÄÜüÖö]"," ",$html);
$words = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $html);
```

doesnt this replace all non (A-Z, a-z, a o u with umlauts) characters with space?
I am losing words like zugänglich etc with umlauts

is there any thing wrong with the regex?

edit:

I replaced ereg_replace with preg_replace but somehow the special characters like :, ® are not getting replace by space...

Comment: why not just use preg_split, and put the `[^A-Za-zäÄÜüÖö]` pattern in there? Also, `ereg_replace` is deprecated as of 5.3.0, so I wouldn't use it.

Comment: `ereg_replace()` is deprecated since 5.3, better `use preg_replace()`

Answer (score 3):

If you succeed with your approach foremost depends on the encoding. When all umlauts got stripped, it's likely that your source text (or php script) was encoded as UTF-8.

In this case rather use:

```
$text = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}]/u', " ", $text);
```

This will match all letter characters, not just umlauts. And `/u` solves your likely charset problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, your umlauts are still html-entities (&auml; etc.) which contain non alphanumeric characters, that would be deleted...

BTW: Alphanumeric isn't just a-Z but numbers as well...

Answer (score 0):

the regex should be `/[^A-Za-zäÄÜüÖö]+/`